# How to match two cells of data on different sheets and then pull a specific cell back to another sheet

Tags: excel-formula

I've created a multi-sheet workbook that has Manifest Data (Sheet1), Sammy (Sheet2), Trev (sheet3), Scan Data In (Sheet4). On each of the worksheets is a column labeled Connote and the data within cells of the column relates to a barcode on the paperwork we use. When I open a drivers worksheet i will scan the barcode from the paperwork and information will be pulled from the Manifest Sheet as well Time/Date Stamping using VBA. But what I'm trying to do is pull the drivers name which is in a cell on their worksheet back to the Manifest Data sheet which relates to the connote they have just scanned. I'm happy to upload the working sheet if required. [Manifest Data Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTrAY.png) [Drivers Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAAXJ.png) https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiXQNwMzQ3OrnCxn4D54gpnBH9V0?e=fxsTnz

Comment: apologies James, this is hard to write down what I'm trying to get across plus I'm a newbie on the site. I've just figured out how to add a screenshot :)

Comment: thanks mate, basically on the Manifest Data Sheet we want to know who scanned has the information on their sheet. appreaicate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**QUICK & DIRECT** but limited (update)

Include following function in Manifest under the driver column (assuming driver names are Sammy, Jose, Ian, Tame, etc.):

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sammy!A:A,0))),"Sammy", IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Jose!A:A,0))),"Jose", IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Ian!A:A,0))),"Ian", IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Trev!A:A,0))),"Trev", IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Iwi!A:A,0))),"Iwi","no match as yet")))))
```

Voila!

If there's a match, it will show, else it will show "not match as yet" (you should be able to customize this message fairly easily, even as novice! :)

But if you get stuck with anything else, let me know.  Will sort pronto.  *Just trying to make new joiners feel as welcome as possible Mr Stackoverflow editor! :)*

**Limitation:**

There is a limitation on the number of nested 'if' statements you can have, but this is far quicker than creating additional lookups per tab, then creating a single list based upon FilterXML, then doing a lookup to that list (per below).  However, if you anticipate having scores of drivers (as in plenty of them), then below would work out better than above.

There are 2 further options I can advise upon:

1. Harness VB - given your code / workbooks are already 'VB' 'friendly' (as you've mentioned)
2. Maintain a central table that contains all of the drivers, and even the associated Manifest data if you really want.

**FILTERXML** (harder/longer to implement/build, but robust and durable)

1. Create an additional column in each of your driver sheets (say, in column K for argument sake), that contains the driver name & "-" & Barcode (where barcode exists).  E.g.:

   =IF(A5="","",$C$2&"-"&A5)

where A5 = Barcode, $C$2 = Driver name

2. Insert extra sheet and create a FilterXML to combine all of these columns into a single list (in this example, I only take first 42 rows for each of the driver-name sheet (ignore funky strikethrough - this is stackoverflow's doing not mine - screenshot attests):

   =FILTERXML(
   "<s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Sammy!$K$5:$K$42)&
   "</s><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Jose!$K$5:$K$42)&
   "</s><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Ian!$K$5:$K$42)&
   "</s><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Tame!$K$5:$K$42)&
   "</s><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Trev!$K$5:$K$42)&
   "</s><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Iwi!$K$4:$K$42)&
   "</s>","//s[not(preceding::*=.)]")

[image: Sample picture of Combined Driver-Barcode List]

3. Finally, in your Manifest sheet, you can do a lookup from the Connote (Barcode, right?) to the single Filter-XML sheet/list.  A bit of cleaning with mid function to extract just the name and not the 'Barcode-Name' lookup value from step 1 gives something like this in the Driver field of the Manifest sheet:

   =IFERROR(MID(INDEX(FilterXML!B2#,MATCH("*"&A35&"*",FilterXML!B2#,0)),1,SEARCH("-",INDEX(FilterXML!B2#,MATCH("*"&A35&"*",FilterXML!B2#,0)))-1),"")

Comment: Thanks James , I’ll give that a go and see how it works and respond with any addition questions or answers. Appreciate the time and effort on this one.

Comment: Hi James, I'm stuck on the FilterXML and creating that, absolute pure novice at excel in terms of advanced stuff like this.

Comment: Give my update a go - that should work immediately,  You can get rid of all the extra bits and bobs e.g. FilterXML. extra columns in other sheets etc.

Comment: James, brilliant work my friend, works perfectly. I'd be adding maybe a couple more TABS for extra drivers etc but changing drivers names when they move on from the Company and then changing the formula to work will be simple enough. But I do appreciate the time to help out on this one. I've certainly learnt from this exercise.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  You can/should be able to add more names but as I've said, if you envisage adding very many in near future then it may be worth requesting resource/time to develop/set this monitoring tool up properly from the outset (using FilterXML) orr something.  You could get something like this done through Freelancer (with compensation commensurate to the task at hand I imagine).  Otherwise it'll end up costing more time/headache in the future (only after things breakdown, assuming you notice!:)